# Clear session if you leave the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have paging on the Index page. And if you select a row and edit the row and save the record you will return to the index with the previous selected row and page visible. So that works nice :). But if you go now to a other view(controller) and return back to the page where you updated the record the paging is begins not on page 1 but begins on the page where you earlier edit the record. So how to manage that you will return to page 1.

I have this:

```
[Route("sort/{SortColumn}/{SortOrder?}", Name = "Sort-SubmittedForms")]
[Route("sort/{SortColumn}/{SortOrder?}", Name = "Sort-SubmittedForms")]
[Route("page/{Page:int}/{SortColumn}/{SortOrder?}", Name = "Paging-SubmittedForms")]
[Route("search/{SearchString}")]
[Route()]
public ActionResult Index(string searchString, string filter, string currentFilter, string sortColumn, string sortOrder, int? page)
{
    IOrderedQueryable<SubmittedForm> entities = db.FilteredSubmittedForms;

    if (searchString != null) page = 1; else searchString = currentFilter;
    if (page == null && Session["SubmittedFormpage"] != null)
        page = (int)Session["SubmittedFormpage"];

    bool isHandler = ApplicationUserManager.IsProductHandler(this.User);

    bool hideArchivedOrders = true;

    if (filter != null) {
        int productId = 0;
        string stateFilter = null;
        if (filter.StartsWith("o_")) {  // Order state
            if (isHandler)
                filter = null;
            else {
                stateFilter = filter.Substring(2);
                OrderState oState = db.OrderStates.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Code == stateFilter);
                if (oState == null)
                    filter = null;
                else {
                    entities = (IOrderedQueryable<SubmittedForm>)entities.Where(
                                s => s.Order.OrderState.Code == stateFilter
                        );
                    AddFixedNotification(String.Format(Resources.Entity.Environment.FitleredByOrderStateMessage, oState.Title));
                    hideArchivedOrders = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (filter.StartsWith("s_")) { // Submitted form state
            stateFilter = filter.Substring(2);
            SubmittedFormStateEnum sfState;
            if (SubmittedFormState.TryCodeToId(stateFilter, out sfState)) {
                entities = (IOrderedQueryable<SubmittedForm>)entities.Where(
                            s => s.SubmittedFormStateId == (int) sfState
                                && s.Order.OrderState.Code == OrderState.CompletedCode
                    );
                AddFixedNotification(String.Format(Resources.Entity.Environment.FilteredBySubmittedFormStateMessage, SubmittedFormState.IdToLocalizedName(sfState)));
            }
            else {
                filter = null;
            }
        }
        else if (int.TryParse(filter, out productId) && productId > 0) {
            Product product = db.Products.Find(productId);
            if (product == null) productId = 0;
            else {
                entities = (IOrderedQueryable<SubmittedForm>)entities.Where(
                        s => s.Product.Id == productId
                );
                AddFixedNotification(String.Format(Resources.Entity.Environment.FilteredByProductMessage, product.Name));
            }
            filter = productId.ToString();
        }
        else
            filter = null;
    }

    if (isHandler) {
        entities = FilterSubmittedFormsForProductHandler(entities);
    }
    else if (hideArchivedOrders) {
        entities = (IOrderedQueryable<SubmittedForm>)entities.Where(
                            s => s.Order.OrderState.Code != OrderState.ArchivedCode
                    );
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)) {
        entities = (IOrderedQueryable<SubmittedForm>)entities.Where(
                s => s.Product.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
        );
        AddFixedNotification(String.Format(Resources.Entity.Environment.FilteredBySearchTermMessage, searchString));
    }

    switch (sortColumn) {
        case "id":
            entities = (sortOrder == "desc") ? entities.OrderByDescending(s => s.Id) : entities.OrderBy(s => s.Id);
            break;
        case "product":
            entities = (sortOrder == "desc") ? entities.OrderByDescending(s => s.Product.Name) : entities.OrderBy(s => s.Product.Name);
            break;
        case "modified":
            entities = (sortOrder == "desc") ? entities.OrderByDescending(s => s.ModificationDate) : entities.OrderBy(s => s.ModificationDate);
            break;
        case "attach":
            entities = (sortOrder == "desc") ? entities.OrderByDescending(s => s.SubmittedFormAttachments.Count) : entities.OrderBy(s => s.SubmittedFormAttachments.Count);
            break;
        case "orderstate":
            entities = (sortOrder == "desc") ? entities.OrderByDescending(s => s.Order.OrderStateId) : entities.OrderBy(s => s.Order.OrderStateId);
            break;
        default:
            sortColumn = "id";
            sortOrder = "desc";
            entities = (sortOrder == "desc") ? entities.OrderByDescending(s => s.Id) : entities.OrderBy(s => s.Id);
            break;
    }

    ViewBag.SortColumn = sortColumn;
    ViewBag.SortOrder = sortOrder == "desc" ? "desc" : "";
    ViewBag.SearchString = searchString;
    ViewBag.Filter= filter;
    Session["SubmittedFormpage"] = page;


    if (isHandler)
        ViewBag.OrderStates = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    else
        ViewBag.OrderStates = db.OrderStates.ToDictionary(s => s.Code, s => s.Title);

    bool production = !StateHelper.IsTestMode();
    ViewBag.ProductsInUse = db.Products.Where(p => p.SubmittedForms.Where(f => f.Order.IsProduction == production).Count() != 0)
        .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Id.ToString(), p => p.Name + " (" + p.SubmittedForms.Where(f => f.Order.IsProduction == production).Count() + ")");

    int pageSize = StateHelper.GetPageSize();
    int pageNumber = StateHelper.HasPageSizeChanged ? 1 : (page ?? 1);

    if (Session["SubmittedFormid"] != null) {
        int fid = (int)(Session["SubmittedFormid"]);
        //object p = entities.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id.Equals(fid));
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<SubmittedForm>> pp = entities.Partition(pageSize);
        //int calculatedPage = 0;
        foreach (var item in pp) {
            Debug.Print(pp.Count().ToString());
        }
    }

    return View(entities.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

Thank you

Comment: The behaviour is due to browser caching, what you can probably do is disable client caching for that particular `Action`. Perhaps you can try this `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]`. Decorate your `Index` action with that and see if the browser obeys.

Comment: (unrelated) your controller is getting kinda big. Have you considered using a service layer?

Answer (score 0):

you have to assign the session to 1 while going from one view to another view. then next time it will return to first page.

Session["SubmittedFormpage"]=1;